# Two lines above initial in Gregorio

Tags: gregorio

I'm using gregorio to write a gregorian chant.
In that chant, I would like to have two lines above the initial.
Unfortunately, in the TeX file, there's only a command which produces a single line of text above the initial.
I read that there's also support for having two lines above the initial, but I didn't find a step-by-step description anywhere.
Can anyone of you guys help here?

This is the TeX

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8

% This is a simple template for a LuaLaTeX document using gregorio scores.

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

% usual packages loading:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a5paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\usepackage{gregoriotex} % for gregorio score inclusion
\usepackage{fullpage} % to reduce the margins

% to change the font to something better, you can install the kpfonts package (if not already installed). To do so
% go open the "TeX Live Manager" in the Menu Start->All Programs->TeX Live 2010

% here we begin the document
\begin{document}

% The title:
\begin{center}\begin{huge}\textsc{Rorate caeli}\end{huge}\end{center}

% Here we set the space around the initial.
% Please report to http://home.gna.org/gregorio/gregoriotex/details for more details and options
\setspaceafterinitial{2.2mm plus 0em minus 0em}
\setspacebeforeinitial{2.2mm plus 0em minus 0em}

% Here we set the initial font. Change 43 if you want a bigger initial.
\def\greinitialformat#1{%
{\fontsize{43}{43}\selectfont #1}%
}

% We set red lines here, comment it if you want black ones.
\redlines

% *** This part creates one line above the initial, but I would like to have two...
% ***
% We set VII above the initial.
%\gresetfirstlineaboveinitial{\small \textsc{\textbf{Intr.\newline I}}}{\small \textsc\textbf{Intr.\newline I}}
% ***
% **********************************************************************************

% We type a text in the top right corner of the score:
\commentary{{\small \emph{Is. 45,8}}}

% and finally we include the score. The file must be in the same directory as this one.
\includescore{rorate.tex}

\end{document}
```

The source file for gregorio is here:

```
% !TEX TS-program = gregorio
name:Rorate caeli;
annotation: Intr.;
annotation: I;
%%
(c4)RO(ixcd)-rá(dh'iv)te(h') *(,)cae(hjjh)li(h_g) dé-(hiwj)su(j.ijwkjk)per,(kj..) (;) %
et(f) nu-(ixhih)bes(g) plu-(jjh)ant(h.) ju-(g_f/hGFgf)stum:(f.) (:) %
a-(f)pe(g)ri(h)á(hiwj)tur(g) ter-(fgG'D)ra,(d.) (;) %
et(dfe) gér(fg)mi-(g)net(fgFD.) Sal-(dewf)va(ced)tó(d_e_d_)rem.(d.) <i>Ps.</i>(::) %
Cae-(f)li(gh) en(h)árr(h)ant(h) gló-(hj)ri(h)am(h) De-(hg)i:(g.h.) *(:) %
et(gf) ó(gh)pe-(h)ra(h) má(h)nu-(h)um(h) e-(h)jus(h.) (,) an(h)nún(h)ti-(h)at(hjh) fir(g')ma(g)mén-(ggg)tum(d.) (::) %
Gló-(f)ri(gh)a(h) Pa(h)tri.(h) (::) E(h) u(hjh) o(g') u(f) a(fff) e.(dc/d.f.) (::)
```

The file is named rorate.gabc and it will be compiled to rorate.tex by gregorio.
This rorate.tex is included in the luaLaTex file above.
I've marked the part in the luaLaTeX file which allows me to create one annotation line above the initial. This is working fine. But I would like to have two lines above that.

Comment: In order to help you better, could you provide the community with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what problems you're experiencing. Helping us in this way, ultimately helps you.

Comment: added source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this code

```
\gresetfirstlineaboveinitial
 {\small\bfseries\smash{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Intr.\\ I\end{tabular}}}
 {\small\bfseries\smash{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Intr.\\ I\end{tabular}}}
```

I get the following

[image]